# How can I initialize a vector of object pointers while not knowing how many objects will be created?

Tags: c++, vector

This code is not running properly as it keeps returning 0xC0000005 on codeblocks and on CMD nothing happens. I checked online and it says I should initialize the vector before I write to it but how can I initialize a vector of objects if I don't know how many objects the user is gonna enter(as it should be increasing the more inputs the user uses).

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class stock {
private:
    int sharenumber;
    float shareprice;
    string sharename;
public:
    stock(int x, string y,float z)
    :sharenumber(x),sharename(y),shareprice(z)
    {
        cout<<"An object has been created";
    }

    string getstring(){
        return sharename;
    }


};

int toint(char * x){
   int y;
   y = atoi(x);
   return y;
}

string tostring(char * x){
   stringstream ss;
   string z;
    ss<<x;
    z = ss.str();
   return z;
}

float tofloat(char * x){
   float u;
   u = atof(x);
   return u;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str1[]= "buy";

   vector <stock*> P_obj;

 if (strcmp(str1,argv[1]) == 0){
    cout<<"this ran"<<endl;
   P_obj.push_back(new stock(toint(argv[2]),tostring(argv[3]),tofloat(argv[4])));
    cout<<P_obj[0]->getstring();
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `tostring` function is way overcomplicated. You can simply write `std::string(argv[3])` to convert char* to string.

Comment: I don't think your issue is the `vector`. I suspect you're not actually getting `4` arguments via `argv`. What value does `argc` contain?

Comment: argc contains the number of arguements. But it's all good, I got my answer already. Adding a check for number of arguements makes it so I can check and I was debugging it incorrectly. This is what happens when I am too green and inexperienced.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the number of input before using the input. The `argc` argument will indicate how many inputs are given as the command line argument (including the first argument, which is typically the name of the executable file).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str1[]= "buy";

    vector <stock*> P_obj;

    if (argc > 1){ // check the number of input
        if (strcmp(str1,argv[1]) == 0){
            cout<<"this ran"<<endl;
            if (argc > 4) { // check the number of input
                P_obj.push_back(new stock(toint(argv[2]),tostring(argv[3]),tofloat(argv[4])));
                cout<<P_obj[0]->getstring();
            } else {
                cout<<"too few arguments for "<<str1<<endl;
            }
        }
    } else {
        cout<<"no command"<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```